# Is it possible to use the a aov function in R even when there is no linear dependence between y and x?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, p-value

In [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r) website I found that the `aov` function in R answers to the question: *We want to know if there is any significant difference between the average weights of plants in the 3 experimental conditions.* Can we use it to check if the means of different groups are different even if the dependent variable y does not depend linearly con x? For example if I have a situation like the one in the figure:

[image]

I made the analysis of variance with `ao`v function to know if there is any significant difference between the average quantity of mRNA produced in the different experimental conditions. But there is no linear relationship between the mRNA produced (y) and the experimental conditions (x). The p-value that I computed in this way is lower than the significant threshold that I set 0.05. Can I conclude that the there is a significant difference between the average quantities of the different groups ?

Comment: Could you give us more details on your data (e.g. a summary, or text dump of the first few rows)? What exactly is the model you are using (e.g. R's formula for it)?

Comment: @Tim♦ Ok if you need I add more details about the code, but I simply used the `aov` function in which I put the mRNA produced as dependent variable and the Time as covariate, and the output is a p-value lower than 0.05... I wanted just to know if it is right to use the analysis of variance when there is no linear dipendence between y and x .

Comment: But what is your data? Time is coded as a number, or as R's `factor`? Both cases would mean using quite different models.